# Sum elements of a list in Python

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

I want to add all elements and form:

```
a = [6] Or a = 6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the built in [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function:

```
print sum(a)
# 6
```

If you want to assign `a` to the result, just do `a = sum(a)`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
 a = [1, 2, 3]
 b = [sum(a)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a single element with a value of previous elements, then this is the easy and nice way:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a = sum(a)
```

or simply access it with `sum(a)` whenever you need the sum, but you dont want to alter the structure of `a[]`. The above method is slightly better from the method posted by nconnector, because you're avoiding creating another object in memory (`b[]`).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `reduce` and `lambda`functions:

```
 reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, a)
```

Comment: use `operator.add` instead of `lambda`.